# Slidingdrawer position changes while adjust it's height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created sliding drawer for my relative layout which includes some buttons. But when I adjust the height of the drawer the drawer button position changes instead of it's height. Here is my xml file.......

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <com.measure.sizemesurment2.MyView
    android:id="@+id/DrawViewId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </com.measure.sizemesurment2.MyView >

  <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

  <Button
     android:id="@id/handle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@id/content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/left"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
         android:src="@drawable/left" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/right"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
         android:src="@drawable/right" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/up"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
         android:src="@drawable/up" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/down"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
         android:src="@drawable/down" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/plus"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
         android:text="+"
         android:textSize="20dp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/minus"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
         android:text="-"
         android:textSize="20dp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/ok"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
         android:text="OK"
         android:textSize="20dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</FrameLayout>
```

where MyView is a class used to draw on canvas. When I set SlidingDrawer height to fill parent I am getting button on the bottom side of my layout. But it's height is parent's height, I need limited height and all my buttons should position on the bottom of the layout... 
Thanks in advance.....

Hi here is my image I am getting, First one is resulted when set siding drwer height "fill_parent" and the second is for 100dip

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its happening because all your buttons are residing in RelativeLayout which is the child of SliderDrawable, So you need to take out your button from it,

Do something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:text="^"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

  <com.measure.sizemesurment2.MyView
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear_bottom"
    android:id="@+id/DrawViewId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </com.measure.sizemesurment2.MyView >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/down"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
            android:text="OK" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi made the change as you said.....But the drawer button is not visible. The layout showing only buttons.

Comment: @Haris: Why did you edit hotveryspicy's answer?! Add that as an comment. For reference, your edit was:  > Hi When I edit the code I am getting the image like this when activity started 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/o7IF9.jpg
The only change I made is that set source for image buttons....

Comment: Sorry for that I am beginner here